# Why does silver lose its magnetic moment?

Tags: condensed-matter, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

By the Gerlach-Stern experiment, the silver atom has a net magnetic moment. But silver as a metal is not magnetic. Or more precisely, it does not show any permanent magnetic moment.

What is the reason behind? How about a cluster of silver atoms?

Comment: This might be more suitable for ChemistrySE.

Comment: The properties of bulk silver where atoms are randomly oriented are surely different from those individual silver atoms, as were used in the SG experiment.

Comment: The question I've linked above refers to copper, but exactly the same argument applies to silver.